# How to access a server running on a local network

Tags: python, django, macos, server, localhost

I'm running a Django based server on a Mac. When running it using the default "python manage.py runserver" I can access it through a browser using "http://127.0.0.1:8000/".

The thing is I want to access it from other machines on the network. When I go to network settings I can see that the IP is for example 10.0.0.15. In the past I used to be able to run a Django based server using "python manage.py runserver 10.0.0.15:8000" and then access it using that address from any other machine in the local network, including the machine running the server.

Now, when I'm trying to access it using "http://10.0.0.15:8000/" even from a browser on the same machine I can see in the terminal that the server has received a request, but I get a Bad Request (400) response. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` as Leonardo Andrade suggested. It still didn't work, but it was the first part of the solution. The problem was that the `DEBUG` setting was `False`. In that case Django takes into account the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

Possible solutions:

1. Set `DEBUG` setting to `True`. This is a good idea for debugging anyway. `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting is not taken into account in that case.
2. Keep `DEBUG` setting as `False` and add to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` `'0.0.0.0'` or `'*'` or your local ip (e.g. `'10.0.0.15'`). This is only for testing purposes. Make sure you don't allow just any hosts when you run a production server.

Of course, run the server on `0.0.0.0:8000`.

A nice solution for accessing the server from other machines when the server runs an OS X is to go to Settings->Sharing on your Mac. There, under Computer Name you can see the name other computers can use to access this computer in a local network (e.g. `my-mac.local`). You can add that name to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and then access the server using it (e.g. `http://my-mac.local:8000/`).

Comment: Is `10.0.0.*` an option for allowing hosts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`